# Xcode "Project" versus "project", removing association with SVN working copies

Tags: xcode, svn

If I do a fresh checkout of a project to a new working directory location using svn command line "svn checkout " and then open the new foo.xcodeproject it retains references to previous working copy location.  Under the Source Control menu it will show both the new working copy and the old.  And, in the "Issues Inspector" there are 2 headings "foo Project" and "foo project".  The one with capital P has a different icon I have never seen before, and lists 1000's of issues for missing files from the old working directory (which I deleted from file system).

How do I get XCode to forget about this old working directory?  The missing files have nothing to do with Xcode, but are in the repository for Android build.  I have never referenced them within Xcode, but I guess it has decided to manage them since they are referenced by .svn files.  This will sometimes block my checkins due to tree conflicts.  I figured out how to do an svn "sparse" checkout to exclude these files from my local working copy, which seems to have mostly solved this problem, except that Xcode is still trying to find those files in the previous working copy that did not do sparse checkout.

So, how to manage the files Xcode thinks are part of the capital P Project?  Or, how to control what working copies appear under Source Control menu?  I see options to configure, but not remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep -R on foo.xcodeproj revealed there were some absolute file paths in the project configuration which were referencing files in the old working copy.  This caused XCode to bring the old working directory into the project workspace.  Making sure all file paths were relative to the project fixed the problem.